# GroupBy on multiple objects gives [SlickException: Cannot select Path s2 in Ref s3]

Tags: scala, slick

I am writing a query that calculates a possible score for a QuestionAnswer, when executing the query I get a SlickException

**Info about the model**

A QuestionAnswer can have several (at least one) questionAnswerPossibilities, since there are multiple ways to answer the question correctly.

Every questionAnswerPossibility has several questionAnswerParts, in the query below we query the score per questionAnswerPossibility.

**The Problematic Query**
This is the query that gives the exception

```
  def queryAnswersWithScore()(implicit session: Session) = {
    (for{
      ovam <- OpenVraagAntwoordMogelijkheden //questionAnswerPossibility
      ovad <- OpenVraagAntwoordOnderdelen if ovad.ovamId === ovam.id //questionAnswerPart
      ova <- OpenVraagAntwoorden if ovam.ovaId === ova.id //questionAnswer
    } yield (ova, ovam, ovad.score))
      .groupBy{ case (ova, ovam, score) => (ova, ovam)}
      .map{ case ((ova, ovam), query) => ((ova, ovam), query.map(_._3).sum)}
  }
```

However when executing this query, I get the following exception. (it is thrown when .list is called on the query object)

```
lay.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[SlickException: Cannot select Path s2 in Ref s3]]
    at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:289) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.3]
    at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:383) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.3]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$handleAction$1$2$$anonfun$apply$21.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:415) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.3]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$handleAction$1$2$$anonfun$apply$21.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:415) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.3]
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$handleAction$1$2.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:415) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.3]
scala.slick.SlickException: Cannot select Path s2 in Ref s3
    at scala.slick.compiler.FuseComprehensions.select(Relational.scala:348) ~[slick_2.10-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]
    at scala.slick.compiler.ConvertToComprehensions$$anonfun$5.applyOrElse(Relational.scala:126) ~[slick_2.10-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]
    at scala.slick.compiler.ConvertToComprehensions$$anonfun$5.applyOrElse(Relational.scala:119) ~[slick_2.10-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]
    at scala.slick.ast.NodeOps$.replace(Util.scala:95) ~[slick_2.10-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]
    at scala.slick.ast.NodeOps$.replace$extension(Util.scala:52) ~[slick_2.10-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]
    at scala.slick.ast.NodeOps$$anonfun$replace$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$1.apply(Util.scala:95) ~[slick_2.10-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]
```

**A working, similar query**
This alternative for the query does work, the difference here is that I do not select the questionAnswer (ova) object. When I call group by on one object, everything works just fine

```
  def queryAnswersWithScore()(implicit session: Session) = {
    (for{
      ovam <- OpenVraagAntwoordMogelijkheden //questionAnswerPossibility
      ovad <- OpenVraagAntwoordOnderdelen if ovad.ovamId === ovam.id //questionAnswerPart
    } yield (ovam, ovad.score))
      .groupBy{ case (ovam, score) => ovam}
      .map{ case (ovam, query) => (ovam, query.map(_._2).sum)}
  }
```

This alternative query is not a solution for my problem, since I really want a query that selects the score for every questionAnswer, which is calculated by choosing the maximum score from the questionAnswerPossibilities for this questionAnswer

## update

I updated my query and now I got it to generate sql, however the result is invalid.
See
[Groupby on multiple objects generates invalid SQL in slick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18726742/groupby-on-multiple-objects-generates-invalid-sql-in-slick)

Comment: File a bug on github https://github.com/slick/slick

Comment: I have already done this for the related issue: https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/207 .